# Sharepoint user details not visible to other users

Tags: sharepoint

I am managing a SharePoint site that uses Form Based Authentication.  We have several generic lists, document libraries and active task lists that users can create update and delete.  Users can use the people pickers to select/search for everyone.  But the users cannot see other users names, email addresses etc. in display lists or the people pickers.  If I log in as the site collection administrator, I can see everyones details. So I know the data is available.

Updated details on this problem
(non-administrators) SharePoint users cannot see other users information.  Example:  User A assigns a task to user B.  User A creates a new task and uses the people picker to find user B.  User B is only visible by the login name “bname” and any information about user B is not visible or searchable within the people picker.  Once user B is assigned the task, user A no longer sees the name in the task list – even though user A created it.  No modified by, created by, assigned to or owner field data is visible to non-administrator users.
Facts:

1. Extranet site is configured to use Forms Based Authentication.
2. Intranet uses windows based authentication
3. Users of both the intranet and extranet have the same problem
4. All databases are local
5. The site uses SSRS integration
6. SharePoint WSS on Windows 2003 Std

--
After activating the verbose logging it looks like SharePoint is definately asking SQL server for only the user info for the currently logged in user:

SELECT TOP 6 /*lots-of-columns*/
FROM
    UserData INNER MERGE  JOIN Docs AS t1
ON
    (
        1 = 1
    AND
        UserData.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0
    AND
        t1.SiteId = UserData.tp_SiteId
    AND
        t1.SiteId = @L2
    AND
        t1.DirName = UserData.tp_DirName
    AND
        t1.LeafName = UserData.tp_LeafName
    AND
        t1.Level = UserData.tp_Level
    AND
        t1.IsCurrentVersion = 1
    AND
        (1 = 1)
    )
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    AllUserData AS t2
ON
    (
        UserData.[tp_Author]=t2.[tp_ID]
    AND
        UserData.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0
    AND
        t2.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0
    AND
        (
        (t2.tp_IsCurrent = 1)
        )
    AND
        t2.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = 0
    AND
        t2.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = 0x
    AND
        t2.tp_ListId = @L3
    AND
        UserData.tp_ListId = @L4
    AND
        t2.[tp_Author]=162   /*** this is the currently logged in user ***/
    )
WHERE
    (UserData.tp_IsCurrent = 1)
AND
    UserData.tp_SiteId=@L2
AND
    (UserData.tp_DirName=@DN)
AND
    UserData.tp_RowOrdinal=0
AND
    (
        (
            (UserData.[datetime1] IS NULL )
        OR
            (UserData.[datetime1] >= @L5DTP)
        )
    AND
        t1.SiteId=@L2
    AND
        (t1.DirName=@DN)
    )
ORDER BY
    UserData.[tp_Modified] Desc,
    UserData.[tp_ID] Asc

Again, any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After working through the "impossible", it was pointed out to me to look at the permissions for the user list.  So I navigated:  Site Actions>Site Settings>People and Groups>Settings>List settings>Advanced Settings>  and noticed that the users were set to be able to only view their own user item..  I hope this helps someone else out.